# How can I debug a deadlocked rippled?

Tags: rippled

My dogfood machine hit a deadlock earlier this morning in a debug build. It's at a breakpoint in gdb now. What is my best next step before I kill it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off pagination: `set pagination off`
2. Turn on logging: `set logging on`
3. Get a stack trace: `thread apply all bt`
4. Get a core dump in case we want more info: `generate-core-file`
5. Confirm the core file and log file are reasonable (the core file should be binary, the log file should be text, both should be non-empty) before exiting from gdb.
6. Upload the log file to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com) so we can all see it.